# Creating a class over a single variable in java

Tags: java

If you are creating a library to be re-used does it make sense (or in general usage), to create a class over a single dataype/variable. So for instance,

```
class DataSet
{
 private HashMap<String,String> mapping;
 public String getKey();
 public String getValue(String key);
}
```

Let's say I have a method `DataSet getDataSet()`, Does it make sense to have this method in my API that returns HashMap or should it return DataSet?

Some benefits of returning DataSet over java collection type are -

- Code is easy to very verbose and easy to read.
- Writing unit tests at class level.
- Finer control on internal storage structure - user cannot directly modify that collection.

Are there are disadvantages to this approach? Or is it always recommended especially when creating APIs/libraries to use own classes instead of known java datatypes?

Comment: Kill me but I do not understand what do you mean. How methods `getDataSet()` and special method with `HashMap` return value are related to *creating a class over a single variable*? And how these all things relate to `java`?

Comment: You are describing a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). An example of a class in the Java API which does this is `HashSet`: it's actually implemented basically as a wrapper around a `HashMap`. The (a) reason for doing this is that `HashMap` provides the necessary functionality (so there is no point in reimplementing it), *but `Set` is a more appropriate interface*. Sure, you could deal with the `Map` directly, but it makes more sense to deal with a `Set` if your code logically deals with sets.

Comment: I suggestion of mine is whatever you make: your objects should be immutable. If you have a map than also return a map, that is what I would offer. If somthing else is needed, than expand the api.

Comment: Just a side question: if you internally have a map with multiple keys (otherwise you'd not need a map), what should `getKey()` do?

Comment: @Adremoniy probably I didn't frame the question well enough - I was in a hurry. But yes, I think I got the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wrappers in general**

As for the general question on whether to use wrappers or not that depends on the reasons and it may vary between use cases.

Some advantages of wrappers

- Type safety: you could wrap a primitive to provide some sematic safety by the compiler. As an example you could use a class `Key` which contains a single string instead of just a `String` to point out that the string inside is meant to be a key. This might help you in cases where multiple strings might get confused.
- Access control: like you described, allow read/write access etc.
- "Manual" AOP: wrap setters/getters with logic.

Some disadvantages:

- Code is more verbose and might get harder to understand/handle.
- More effort is needed to write all those wrappers (and ideally documentation).
- Existing/common datatypes like collections, strings etc. are more widely understood thus easing the learing curve.

**Returning `HashMap`**

If you'd return a map then I'd not return `HashMap<String,String>` but rather `Map<String, String>`.

**Wrapper vs. Map**

Besides that it depends on what you're trying to achieve. Of course using a wrapper object gives you more control of the API at the cost of more code to be maintained.

**Delegation**

Besides using `DataSet` as you described it delegation might be an option, i.e. a class that looks like a map but just delegates calls to an internal map. That way you could add functionality in the methods like preventing write access, validation in a transparent way (for read-only maps there are already delegate wrappers in the `Collections` class).

**Unit tests**

As for the "Writing unit tests at class level." point I'd say that also depends on what the wrapper would do. If it just resembles a map then creating a test for that wrapper only might be somewhat wasted time (you could just use an existing and already tested map implementation). Additionally you'd probably test the functionality that operates on/returns that wrapper/map and those tests would be mostly independent of whether you use a wrapper or a map.

That's just my <strike>2</strike> 50 cents ;)